# JavaFX TreeItem string not appearing

Tags: treeview, javafx

After hours of trying i finally somewhat managed to figure out how to hook a listener to TreeItems in a TreeView, it probably isn't at all the right way to do so but hey it works so far. 
Although one thing isn't, that is the "label" or better said text in the TreeItems isn't showing up anymore.
[image]

Can anyone look at my code and tell me, if i'm either doing it completely wrong or why the text isn't showing up anymore?
Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
TreeView<String> tree = new TreeView<>(); 

TreeItem<String> treeRoot = new TreeItem<>(Login.name + " - " + Login.accountType);
treeRoot.getChildren().addAll(new TreeItem<>("Branches"),
        new TreeItem<>("Planning"), new TreeItem<>("Courses"),
        new TreeItem<>("Add new item"));

treeRoot.getChildren().get(1).getChildren().addAll(
        new TreeItem<>("2014 - Q1"), new TreeItem<>("2014 - Q2"),
        new TreeItem<>("2014 - Q3"), new TreeItem<>("2014 - Q4"));
treeRoot.getChildren().get(3).getChildren().addAll(
        new TreeItem<>("Branch"), new TreeItem<>("Course"));

for(String str : loadBranchData()) {
    treeRoot.getChildren().get(0).getChildren().add(
        new TreeItem<>(str));
}
for(String str : loadCourseData()) {
    treeRoot.getChildren().get(2).getChildren().add(
        new TreeItem<>(str));
}
for(int c = 0; c <= 2; c++) {
    treeRoot.getChildren().get(c).setExpanded(true);
}

treeRoot.setExpanded(true);
tree.setPrefWidth(PREFWIDTH);
tree.setRoot(treeRoot);
tree.setShowRoot(true);
tree.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<String>,TreeCell<String>>(){
    @Override
    public TreeCell<String> call(TreeView<String> p) {
        return new EpicTreeCell();
    }
});
...
    private final class EpicTreeCell extends TreeCell<String> {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        super.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent evt) {
                System.out.println("TEST?");
            }
        });       
    }
```

Comment: The listener does actually work btw, it does print "TEST" to output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the custom cell is defined, the `setText()` method should be called in its overridden `updateItem()` method.

```
private final class EpicTreeCell extends TreeCell<String> {

    public EpicTreeCell() {
        setOnMouseClicked (
                new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent evt) {
                        System.out.println("TEST?");
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
        } else {
            setText(getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString());
        }
        setGraphic(null);
    }
}
```

See the ["Custom Java-fx cellfactory messes up the setCellValueFactory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245822/custom-java-fx-cellfactory-messes-up-the-setcellvaluefactory) for more information.

Comment: Thanks alot, this did it. I had the updateItem() overridden before, but i probably did something wrong then. Thanks a bunch!