# Adding click event to JavaFX TableCell

Tags: java, javafx, mouseevent, tablecell, tablecolumn

I have TableView and I want my program to doSomething() when user clicks on a cell. After searching on Internet (stackoverflow included), I found [this](http://monkeyhash.wordpress.com/2011/10/20/javafx-2-0-table-click-events/).

Tried that method, but I got a compile error on these code :

```
EventHandler click = new EventHandler() {
    public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
        System.out.println("CLICKED");
    }
};
```

NetBeans asked me to override all abscract method, so I did it.

```
EventHandler click = new EventHandler() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
        System.out.println("CLICKED");
    }
};
```

Still got same error :

```
error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

If I remove @Override annotation, I got :

```
error: <anonymous pengamatan.penginderaan.FXMLDocumentController$4> is not abstract and does not override abstract method handle(Event) in EventHandler
```

Any help? Thank you.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Found the solution! Here is the code :

```
....
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
....
....
EventHandler click = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
@Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
        if(t.getClickCount()>1) {
        System.out.println("DOUBLE CLICK");
        }
    }
};
....
```

Hope it helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
cell.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
         System.out.println("cell clicked!");
    }
});
```

found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499269/javafx-tableview-detect-a-doubleclick-on-a-cell)

Comment: I have read that and I imagine how if I have lots of cells, so I am looking for another way. As described http://monkeyhash.wordpress.com/2011/10/20/javafx-2-0-table-click-events/ ,  I can use CellFactory class to do that. I tried that but get an error.