# JavaFX Error when trying to make Tableview Clickable

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to make a tableview clickable, where it will return the text in the cell that is clicked. I am receiving two errors when trying to compile in Netbeans. All of the code was taken from "Example 12-11: Alternative Solution Of Cell Editing" [official tableview tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm) & [from this stackoverflow.com answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499269/javafx-tableview-detect-a-doubleclick-on-a-cell/12591417#12591417). Here are the errors:

1. type argument MouseEvent is not within bounds of type-variable T
               cell.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler() {
   where T is a type-variable:
   T extends Event declared in interface EventHandler
2. method addEventFilter in class Node cannot be applied to given types;
               cell.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler() {
   required: EventType,EventHandler
   found: int,>
   reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that argument type int conforms to formal parameter type EventType
   where T is a type-variable:
   T extends Event declared in method addEventFilter(EventType,EventHandler)

---

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellEditEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class TableViewSample extends Application {

     private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
     private final ObservableList<Person> data =
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
            new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
            new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
            new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
            new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com"));
     final HBox hb = new HBox();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
        stage.setWidth(450);
        stage.setHeight(550);

        final Label label = new Label("Address Book");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

    table.setEditable(false);
        Callback<TableColumn, TableCell> cellFactory =
            new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {
                public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
                    TableCell cell = new TableCell<Person, String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                            super.updateItem(item, empty);
                            setText(empty ? null : getString());
                            setGraphic(null);
                        }

                        private String getString() {
                            return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
                        }
                    };

                cell.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()      {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                        if (event.getClickCount() > 1) {
                            System.out.println("double clicked!");
                            TableCell c = (TableCell) event.getSource();
                            System.out.println("Cell text: " + c.getText());
                        }
                    }
                });
                return cell;
            }
        };

        TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));
        firstNameCol.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
        firstNameCol.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {
                    ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setFirstName(t.getNewValue());
                }
             }
        );


        TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));
        lastNameCol.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
        lastNameCol.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {
                    ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setLastName(t.getNewValue());
                }
            }
        );

        TableColumn emailCol = new TableColumn("Email");
        emailCol.setMinWidth(200);
        emailCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("email"));
        emailCol.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
        emailCol.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {
                    ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setEmail(t.getNewValue());
                }
            }
        );

        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol);

        final TextField addFirstName = new TextField();
        addFirstName.setPromptText("First Name");
        addFirstName.setMaxWidth(firstNameCol.getPrefWidth());
        final TextField addLastName = new TextField();
        addLastName.setMaxWidth(lastNameCol.getPrefWidth());
        addLastName.setPromptText("Last Name");
        final TextField addEmail = new TextField();
        addEmail.setMaxWidth(emailCol.getPrefWidth());
        addEmail.setPromptText("Email");

        final Button addButton = new Button("Add");
        addButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                data.add(new Person(
                        addFirstName.getText(),
                        addLastName.getText(),
                        addEmail.getText()));
                addFirstName.clear();
                addLastName.clear();
                addEmail.clear();
            }
        });

        hb.getChildren().addAll(addFirstName, addLastName, addEmail, addButton);
        hb.setSpacing(3);

        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table, hb);

        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class Person {

        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty email;

        private Person(String fName, String lName, String email) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
            this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String fName) {
            firstName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String fName) {
            lastName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email.get();
        }

        public void setEmail(String fName) {
            email.set(fName);
        }
    }

    class EditingCell extends TableCell<Person, String> {

        private TextField textField;

        public EditingCell() {
        }

        @Override
        public void startEdit() {
            if (!isEmpty()) {
                super.startEdit();
                createTextField();
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
                textField.selectAll();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelEdit() {
            super.cancelEdit();

            setText((String) getItem());
            setGraphic(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                if (isEditing()) {
                    if (textField != null) {
                        textField.setText(getString());
                    }
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(textField);
                } else {
                    setText(getString());
                    setGraphic(null);
                }
            }
        }

        private void createTextField() {
            textField = new TextField(getString());
            textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap()* 2);
            textField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>(){
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, 
                    Boolean arg1, Boolean arg2) {
                        if (!arg2) {
                            commitEdit(textField.getText());
                        }
                }
            });
        }

        private String getString() {
            return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the wrong import for `MouseEvent`. You need `javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent`, not the AWT version.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that when your IDE prompted you to import MouseEvent, the first option was java.awt.event.MouseEvent, rather than javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent.

Be careful while importing with JavaFX, as many of it's classes have the same names as classes in standard Java libraries.